# Oracle: convert tree structure to XML

Tags: xml, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have a simple tree structure, where child elements are connected to parent elements, that I need to convert to XML.

Currently, I use recursive function calls to implement this (i.e. to retrieve the child elements of a given element), which doesn't seem to be the smartest way. A statement involving CONNECT BY PRIOR will output the results, but I have no clue how to convert this to XML.

My simplified data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE ENTRY
  (
    "ID"        NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "PARENT_ID" NUMBER(10,0),
    "TAG"       VARCHAR2(1000 CHAR)
  )
```

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entries>
    <entry>
        <tag>parent A</tag>
        <entries>
            <entry>
                <tag>child A-1</tag>
                <entries>
                    <entry>
                        <tag>grandchild A-1</tag>
                    </entry>
                </entries>
            </entry>
            <entry>
                <tag>child A-2</tag>
            </entry>
        </entries>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <tag>bla parent B</tag>
        <entries>
            <entry>
                <tag>child B-1</tag>
            </entry>
        </entries>
    </entry>
</entries>
```

I'm looking for a single SELECT statement to do this job :)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed, and it doesn't appear to represent a meaningful hierarchical structure.  You need to provide a realistic output to give us a fighting chance of understanding your question.

Comment: OK, full XML now provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive PL/SQL function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getXMLChildren(p_parent_id NUMBER)
  2     RETURN XMLTYPE IS
  3     l XMLTYPE;
  4  BEGIN
  5     SELECT xmlelement("entries",
  6                       xmlagg(xmlelement("entry",
  7                                         xmlelement("tag", tag),
  8                                         getXMLChildren(ID))))
  9       INTO l
 10       FROM ENTRY
 11      WHERE (p_parent_id IS NOT NULL AND parent_ID = p_parent_id)
 12         OR (p_parent_id IS NULL AND parent_id IS NULL) --
 13      HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
 14     RETURN l;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created
```

This function builds the first level, then calls itself on the children:

```
SQL> select XMLSERIALIZE(document getXMLChildren(NULL)
  2                      as CLOB INDENT SIZE = 2) xml
  3    from dual;

XML
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<entries>
  <entry>
    <tag>bla parent</tag>
    <entries>
      <entry>
        <tag>bla child 1</tag>
        <entries>
          <entry>
            <tag>bla grandchild1</tag>
          </entry>
        </entries>
      </entry>
      <entry>
        <tag>bla child 2</tag>
      </entry>
    </entries>
  </entry>
</entries>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's approx. my approach with recursive function calls. Is there a way to implement this using a single SELECT statement? :)

Comment: Yes, using a different approach, see for example [this blog note](http://odieweblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/24/how-to-generate-a-recursive-xml-structure/)